# Leer el dato calculado mediante formula en Excel y pasarlo a Jtable

Tags: java, excel

Tengo ya solucionada la exportación de una hoja Excel a un Jtable en Java.
El problema surge en las celdas del Excel que han sido calculadas mediante formula. En estos casos, el Jtable no interpreta el formato y la exportación se interrumpe. ¿Conocéis alguna solución al respecto? 
Este el código que utilizo.

```
public class importExcel {

    Workbook wb;

    public String Importar (File archivo, JTable tabla){

        String respuesta="No se ha podido importar el fichero Excel.";
        DefaultTableModel modeloT=new DefaultTableModel();
        tabla.setModel(modeloT);
        try{
            wb=WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(archivo));
            Sheet hoja=wb.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator filaIterator=hoja.rowIterator();
            int indiceFila=-1;
            while(filaIterator.hasNext()){
                indiceFila++;
                Row fila=(Row)filaIterator.next();
                Iterator columnaIterator=fila.cellIterator();
                Object[] listaColumna= new Object[20];//Averiguar porque es 5
                int indiceColumna=-1;
                while(columnaIterator.hasNext()){
                    indiceColumna++;
                    Cell celda=(Cell) columnaIterator.next();
                    if(indiceFila==0){
                        modeloT.addColumn(celda.getStringCellValue());
                    }else{
                        if(celda!=null){
                            switch(celda.getCellType()){
                                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                    if( HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(celda) ){
                                    CellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
                                    CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
                                    cellStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd/mm/yyyy"));
                                    //Aqui se puede cortar el bucle con una condición sobre la fecha o cualquier otra cosa
                                    celda.setCellValue(celda.getDateCellValue());
                                    celda.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

                                    listaColumna[indiceColumna]=celda.getDateCellValue();

                            }else{
                                    listaColumna[indiceColumna]=celda.getNumericCellValue();

                            }break;
                                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                    listaColumna[indiceColumna]=celda.getStringCellValue();
                                    break;
                                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                                    listaColumna[indiceColumna]=celda.getBooleanCellValue();
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    listaColumna[indiceColumna]=celda.getDateCellValue();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                }
                if(indiceFila!=0){
                    modeloT.addRow(listaColumna);
                }
            }
            respuesta="Exportación realizada con éxito";
        }catch(Exception e){

        }

        return respuesta;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Este es un ejemplo para Usar DecimalFormat, colocas un patron y este devuelve el valor en formato string y asi lo envias a la tabla.

```
if(cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC)
                          texto = new DecimalFormat("0").format(cell.getNumericCellValue());
```

Otra manera seria darle formato directamente a la tabla convitiendo la columna de interes en el tipo de valor que deseas colocarle. (double)

```
 tabla.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "85.3"
        }
    ) {
        Class[] types = new Class [] {
            java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Double.class
        };

        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return types [columnIndex];
        }
    });
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda. Voy a probar.